# How to enable "Display over other apps" on Redmi A1+

Tags: android, redmi-device, redmi-permission

How to enable Display over other apps on Redmi A1+

I have seen a code that could help circumvent the permission for specific apps, but I don't know how to add the code into the manifest.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.